# CSS position full screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am working with a parallax scrolling example however have troubles with setting the position so that the background covers the entire screen. The scroll works but if you see there is a white border around the screen. I would like it to cover the all way.

```css
.ha-bg-parallax {

    background: url(https://www.geziceki.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/32617393_xl.jpg) no-repeat fixed;

    -moz-background-size: cover;

    -o-background-size: cover;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;

    background-size: cover;

    height: 100vh;

    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 100%;

    display: table;

    vertical-align: middle;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-parallax-body {

    display: table-cell;

    vertical-align: middle;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-content-whitecolor {

    font-size: 17px;

    color: #ffffff;

    width: 45%;

    margin: auto;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-diamond-divider-md {

    margin: 15px 0px;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-heading-parallax {

    font-style: italic;

    font-weight: bold;

    text-transform: none;

    color: #ffffff;

    padding-bottom: 0px;

}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

      <div>

              <div class="ha-bg-parallax text-center block-marginb-none" data-type="background" data-speed="20">

          <div class="ha-parallax-body">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
        <img class="img-circle img-responsive" alt="me" src="image/me.jpg">



        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
  <h1><span class="element"></span></h1>



      </div>

              <div class="ha-parallax-divider-wrapper">

                  <span class="ha-diamond-divider-md img-responsive"></span>

              </div>



          </div>

      </div>


      <div class="container">
      <h2>Normal</h2>


          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
          <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

          </div>




       </div>

       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
      <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

    </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
      <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

    </div>
       </div>

      </div>
  </div>





      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="container">
  <h2>Normal</h2>


      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
      <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

      </div>




    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
  <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
  <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>





  </div>

</div>
<br>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `container-fluid` has padding set to 15px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the container and that you broke the actual structure of bootstrap.
It's always supposed to look like this:

```
.container
    .row
        .col-??-??
```

To fix this, you need to give the div right after your `.container-fluid` the class `row` like so:

```css
.ha-bg-parallax {

    background: url(https://www.geziceki.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/32617393_xl.jpg) no-repeat fixed;

    -moz-background-size: cover;

    -o-background-size: cover;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;

    background-size: cover;

    height: 100vh;

    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 100%;

    display: table;

    vertical-align: middle;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-parallax-body {

    display: table-cell;

    vertical-align: middle;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-content-whitecolor {

    font-size: 17px;

    color: #ffffff;

    width: 45%;

    margin: auto;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-diamond-divider-md {

    margin: 15px 0px;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-heading-parallax {

    font-style: italic;

    font-weight: bold;

    text-transform: none;

    color: #ffffff;

    padding-bottom: 0px;

}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row">

              <div class="ha-bg-parallax text-center block-marginb-none" data-type="background" data-speed="20">

          <div class="ha-parallax-body">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
        <img class="img-circle img-responsive" alt="me" src="image/me.jpg">



        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
  <h1><span class="element"></span></h1>



      </div>

              <div class="ha-parallax-divider-wrapper">

                  <span class="ha-diamond-divider-md img-responsive"></span>

              </div>



          </div>

      </div>


      <div class="container">
      <h2>Normal</h2>


          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
          <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

          </div>




       </div>

       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
      <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

    </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
      <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

    </div>
       </div>

      </div>
  </div>





      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="container">
  <h2>Normal</h2>


      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
      <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

      </div>




    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
  <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<h1>Mobile and Desktop</h1>
  <span class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</span>

</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>





  </div>

</div>
<br>


</body>
</html>
```

That's it, you're covered :)

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark this as solved is the answer suits your needs!

Answer (score 1):

Just use this css below:

```
.container-fluid{
   padding:0;
}
```

Comment: With the code provided this may help, but will further break the actual 'logic' behind bootstraps layout.